name: 'ProjectGraphError' when start next.js application via docker and NX monorepo
docker-compose up --build
[+] Building 535.7s (21/21) FINISHED                                                                                         docker:desktop-linux
=> [static internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                  0.4s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 803B                                                                                                         0.0s
=> [static internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.13.1-alpine                                                                3.3s
=> [static auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                           0.0s
=> [static internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                     0.4s
=> => transferring context: 163B                                                                                                            0.0s
=> [static builder 1/9] FROM docker.io/library/node:20.13.1-alpine@sha256:a7b980c958bfe4d84ee9263badd95a40c8bb50ad5afdb87902c187fefaef0e24  0.0s
=> [static internal] load build context                                                                                                     1.4s
=> => transferring context: 438.37kB                                                                                                        1.0s
=> CACHED [static builder 2/9] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                         0.0s
=> CACHED [static builder 3/9] COPY package*.json nx.json tsconfig.base.json eslint.config.js jest.preset.js ./                             0.0s
=> CACHED [static builder 4/9] COPY ./apps/ambel-static ./apps/ambel-static                                                                 0.0s
=> CACHED [static builder 5/9] COPY ./libs ./libs                                                                                           0.0s
=> [static builder 6/9] RUN npm cache clean --force                                                                                         3.5s
=> [static builder 7/9] RUN npm ci -f                                                                                                     122.2s
=> [static builder 8/9] RUN npx nx reset  # Reset Nx cache                                                                                  7.7s
=> [static builder 9/9] RUN npx nx build ambel-static --verbose                                                                           179.4s
=> [static runner 3/7] COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/apps/ambel-static ./dist                                                       2.3s
=> [static runner 4/7] COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package*.json ./                                                                    6.7s
=> [static runner 5/7] COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/tsconfig.base.json ./                                                               5.0s
=> [static runner 6/7] COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/nx.json ./                                                                          5.2s
=> [static runner 7/7] RUN npm ci -f                                                                                                      134.7s
=> [static] exporting to image                                                                                                             47.7s
=> => exporting layers                                                                                                                     47.6s
=> => writing image sha256:756ea66490be64fb2a9241aa3457fc594c2098f6b4461800f45a848f60d240b7                                                 0.0s
=> => naming to docker.io/library/ambel-frontend-workspace-static                                                                           0.0s
=> [static] resolving provenance for metadata file                                                                                          0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
✔ Container ambel-static  Recreated                                                                                                         0.4s
Attaching to ambel-static
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |  NX   Running target start for project ambel-static and 1 task it depends on:
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | > nx run ambel-static:build
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | > next build
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | > Build error occurred
ambel-static  | Error: Could not create project graph. Please ensure that your workspace is valid.
ambel-static  |     at /usr/src/app/dist/.nx-helpers/with-nx.js:86:23
ambel-static  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
ambel-static  |     at async combined (/usr/src/app/dist/.nx-helpers/compose-plugins.js:12:30)
ambel-static  |     at async normalizeConfig (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/config-shared.js:161:12)
ambel-static  |     at async loadConfig (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:727:28)
ambel-static  |     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
ambel-static  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:374:28
ambel-static  |     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
ambel-static  |     at async build (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:368:9) {
ambel-static  |   [cause]: [Failed to process project graph. Run "nx reset" to fix this. Please report the issue if you keep seeing it.
ambel-static  |         ProjectsWithNoNameError: The projects in the following directories have no name provided:
ambel-static  |       - dist
ambel-static  |         at validateAndNormalizeProjectRootMap (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/utils/project-configuration-utils.js:470:15)
ambel-static  |         at mergeCreateNodesResults (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/utils/project-configuration-utils.js:353:9)
ambel-static  |         at /usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/utils/project-configuration-utils.js:298:85
ambel-static  |         at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
ambel-static  |         at async buildProjectGraphAndSourceMapsWithoutDaemon (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/project-graph.js:81:31)
ambel-static  |         at async createProjectGraphAndSourceMapsAsync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/project-graph.js:216:25)
ambel-static  |         at async createProjectGraphAsync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/project-graph.js:206:39)
ambel-static  |         at async /usr/src/app/dist/.nx-helpers/with-nx.js:83:25
ambel-static  |         at async combined (/usr/src/app/dist/.nx-helpers/compose-plugins.js:12:30)
ambel-static  |         at async normalizeConfig (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/config-shared.js:161:12)] {
ambel-static  |     name: 'ProjectGraphError'
ambel-static  |   }
ambel-static  | }
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  |  NX   Running target start for project ambel-static and 1 task it depends on failed
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | Failed tasks:
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | - ambel-static:build
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.
ambel-static  |
ambel-static  | Warning: command "next build" exited with non-zero status code
ambel-static exited with code 1
I try to run this application after docker build

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
